# Drone CI - Invalid port configuration

Tags: kubernetes, drone.io

Im trying to install Drone CI server in my kubernetes cluster using an argocd app, everything it's up and running but the Drone CI server deployment

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: drone-server
  namespace: droneci
  labels:
    app: drone-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: drone-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: drone-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: drone-server
        image: drone/drone:2.20.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "800Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
        envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: droneci-secret
```

service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: drone-server
  namespace: droneci
  labels:
    app: drone-server
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: drone-server
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

This is the only log I get from the droneci-server pod (giving Back-off error):

```
level=fatal msg="main: invalid configuration" error="Invalid port configuration. See https://community.harness.io/t/drone-server-changing-ports-protocol/11400"
```

I can't understand what is the problem exactly, I believe that the port configuration it's just fine.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but if I apply the deployment first, and then the service, it works